# How to sum two Number type arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to use generics for the next method:

```
    public int[] newArrayTest(int[] arrayToAdd){
        int[] arrayToReturn =  new int[arrayToAdd.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] += arrayToAdd[j];
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
```

Basically, it creates an array from another one like this:

1. The first element is the same,
2. The second is the sum of the first and the second,
3. The third is the sum of the first, the second and the third
4. And so on...

However, I'd like to use float, long, etc.
This is what I tried:

```
    public Number[] newArrayTest(Number[] arrayToAdd){
        Number[] arrayToReturn =  new Number[arrayToAdd.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] += arrayToAdd[j]; // THERE'S AN ERROR HERE
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
```

Is there a way to do so? Thanks in advace :)

Comment: You can't use generics in place of primitives (currently). Unfortunately you have to special-case each different primitive type.

Comment: Two notes on the subject: - Even though arrays are covariant, covariance does not cross the auto(un)boxing boundary. - Due to the fact that arrays are covariant and retained, while generics are invariant and erased, mixing both is a setup for trouble.

Comment: Just to add to what @khelwood has pointed out, the `Number` class doesn't just represent the primitive wrappers, so the `+` operator couldn't necessarily be defined. What you could do is use `doubleValue()` (for example) but this is a messy solution and not what I would be recommended here.

Comment: @HenryTwist The `Number` class does not represent the primitives at all. It represents (among other things) the wrappers.

Comment: Sorry @Turing85 you're right, I meant the primitive wrappers, not the actual primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function to add.

```
public static <T extends Number> T[] newArrayTest(T[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<T> add){
    T[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
        // arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i]; // It is already stored by clone().
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = add.apply(arrayToReturn[i], arrayToAdd[j]);
        }
    }
    return arrayToReturn;
}
```

and

```
Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Double[] doubleArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
BigInteger[] bigIntegerArray = {BigInteger.valueOf(1), BigInteger.valueOf(2),
                                BigInteger.valueOf(3), BigInteger.valueOf(4)};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrayTest(intArray, Integer::sum)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrayTest(doubleArray, Double::sum)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrayTest(bigIntegerArray, BigInteger::add)));
```

result

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
[1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0]
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

You can also do it by standard API [Arrays.parallelPrefix](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator))

```
Arrays.parallelPrefix(intArray, Integer::sum);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

result

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

It can also be done for arrays of primitive types. However, it treats the array destructively.

Comment: Thanks! You should only change this line: `arrayToReturn[i] = add.apply(arrayToReturn[i], arrayToAdd[i]);` for `arrayToReturn[i] = add.apply(arrayToReturn[i], arrayToAdd[j]);`. But everything else is working just fine